# How to call function from an other Specialpage

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have 2 Special Pages on my **wiki**:

```
SpecialOne.php
SpecialTwo.php
```

In the main function of my first page (`wfSpecialOne()`) i want to use functions from my 2nd `Specialpage (X(), Y())`. But debugger says *the method is unknown*.

The same issue when the (now) `static function X()` calls `function A()` which is part of `SpecialTwo.php`

What i did so far:

```
include_once("SpecialTwo.php");

class SpecialOne extends SpecialPage {
  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct( 'One' );
  }
  public function execute( $sub ) {
      $out = $this->getOutput();
      $this->wfSpecialOne();
  }

  function wfSpeicalOne(){
    $var1 = X();
    $var2 = Y();
  }
}
```

My first thought was to make all the functions `static`. But if so I'd have to refactor the function calls in each class to:

```
SpecialTwo::X();
SpecialTwo::Y():
```

Isn't there a better way? or did i miss something?

Comment: Please show us the code of SpecialTwo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your code in such a way that anything that's needed by multiple special pages is in some sort of utility class. Special pages should not reference each other (I won't say it never happens but it's an antipattern).

Unrelatedly, you should never need `include` and similar commands. If you do, you probably did not run `maintenance/generateLocalAutoload.php`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found out that my "fucntions" X() and Y() actually were class methods of SpecialTwo. As i pulled them out of the classblock everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When SpecialTwo.php also extends SpecialPage, SpecialOne could extends SpecialTwo.